# Creating boundary parameter using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, boundaries

I am using QGIS v 3.2. The data set I am using involves *pipelines*. I need to mark an **exclusion zone** which is running *50m either side of the pipeline* for the entire length of the pipeline.

Is there a function which will allow me to do this or do I have to plot it manually?

The reason I ask is that the pipeline is not straight, portraying various bends and curves, which I would find it hard to create a 50m exclusion zone accurately by hand.

Would a possible way, be by duplicating the shapefile and somehow offsetting its coordinates by 50m?

Comment: It seems to me that it's just about creating a buffer: Menu Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Buffer

Comment: Thank you @Christophe, However the pipeline data I am using is a WMS raster, so I don't think I can edit it. would I need to use a WFS-Service version or change it in the SLD-body?

Comment: Out of my skills. I think you need to ask a new question more explicit with an explaination of the data available

Comment: Could you not do a raster to vector conversion and then buffer your vector?

Comment: I tried but the layers could not be generated, when I tried to _polygonize_ the data